# Datatables - Editor: запрос на поиск дубликатов

Tags: php

Работаю над таблицей в datatables, встала задача, показать дублирующиеся строки по имени столбцов таблицы MYSQL.

Синтаксис у представления свой, вот ссылка на мануал по нему:
http://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/

Вот, пример кода:

```
  Editor::inst($db, 'product', 'product.id')->fields(Field::inst('product.date_available')->validator('Validate::dateFormat', array(
        'format' => 'Y-m-d'
    ))->getFormatter('Format::date_sql_to_format', 'Y-m-d')->setFormatter('Format::date_format_to_sql', 'Y-m-d'), Field::inst('product.mbr_view_status'))->leftJoin('product_to_catalog', 'product.id', '=', 'product_to_catalog.product_id')->leftJoin('catalog', 'product_to_catalog.catalog_id', '=', 'catalog.id')->process($_POST)->json();
```

---

Как я понял, в leftJoin можно передавать массив такого типа:

```
array(
    'table' => '',
    'field1' => '',
    'operator' => '',
    'field2' => ''
);
```

---

Сам запрос, который ищет дубликаты выглядит так:

```
SELECT p1.sku, p1.image_url
  FROM ( SELECT sku, image_url
           FROM product
         GROUP 
             BY sku, image_url
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) AS p2
INNER
  JOIN product p1
    ON p1.sku    = p2.sku OR p1.image_url = p2.image_url
```

с двумя именами стобцов таблицы sku и image_url, вот только не понятно, как добавить его к первому коду в посте.

---

тут указано, как передавать массив http://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/array-joins , но синтаксис довольно сложный получется, пытался передать как в мануале, но безуспешно json на выходе с php ошибками :-(( Помогите, понять построение таких запросов, т.к datables очень удобный инструмент для небольших задач, думаю многим пригодится.

Comment: Если у вас проблема с библиотеками из editor - datatables (еще бы знать, что это такое) - то причем тут `php` и `jquery` в тэгах?

Comment: Наверное, потому что она написана на php + jquery, а работа с бд завернута в ООП и мне, как новичку сложно понять руководствуясь только документацией, как сделать подобную выборку повторящихся строк по имени столбцов.

Comment: Поверьте, тем, кто никогда не работал с этой библиотекой, тоже сложно понять как там устроено. И ради вас понимать никто не будет. Максимум, что вы можете получить от *обычного* программиста на php - совет выкинуть библиотеку, которая мешает. Чтобы получить более качественный совет, надо позвать на помощь именно тех программистов, которые уже работали с этой библиотекой.

Comment: Вы правы, это дельный совет. Возможно найдется кто-нибудь, кто работал с ней, т.к. это довольно популярная библиотека для представления табличных данных в сети. Либо придется перелавливать RAW mysql-запрос в самой библиотеке и пробывать заменить перед его выполнением :-(

Comment: обычно эти библиотеки основываются на PDO, т.е. вполне реально использовать дебагер, поставить брейк поинт перед вызовом какого-либо запроса в БД и посмотреть на объект, который для этого используется, в нем наверняка должен быть способ добраться до PDO, в который вполне можно передать этот sql